# Skipping over javascript content on iPad/iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ipad

I have the following code working, but I would like to just skip it altogether if the user is on an iPad or iPhone. How do I go about doing that?

```
<script>
  var elements = ['<video autoplay="true" width="900" height="540" id="myVideo">',
                   '<source src="/s/phlogo.mp4"  type="video/mp4">',
                    '<source src="/s/phlogo.ogg" type="video/ogg">',
                    '<source src="/s/phlogo.webm" type="video/webm">',
                    '</video>'].join('\n');
</script>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $.fancybox.open({
        padding: 0,
        content: elements,
        type: "html"
    });

    $("#myVideo").on("ended", function () {
        $.fancybox.close();
    });

}); // ready
</script>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why? Is there some reason you're thinking about iPhone/iPad specifically, or is this something that should be dealt with using [feature detection](http://modernizr.com/) or [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) instead?

Comment: Well... the people I'm helping with this want their logo to play (with sound) when someone visits the site for the first time (yes, I know auto-playing videos are not optimal; I've given them the arguments against it, but they still want it). 

I'm having difficulty getting it to work at all with idevices (for some reason, the lightbox opens up with an empty image on them now), and anyway, idevices refuse to autoplay videos in any case, so I just want to have it not work at all on them. Regardless, I'm sure there's a better way to handle it than I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends if you're using jQuery or not.

JS:

`if (/iPhone|iPad/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) { //code };`

jQuery([not recommended](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/)):

```
<script>
$.browser.device = (/iPhone/iPad/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));

if ($.browser.device == true) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $.fancybox.open({
            padding: 0,
            content: elements,
            type: "html"
        });

        $("#myVideo").on("ended", function () {
            $.fancybox.close();
        });

    }); // ready
}
</script>
```

Comment: I am using jQuery, sorry, I should have been more clear. Thank you for the quick answer!

But, er... I'm not very experienced with this. Could you show me how to work that into what I already have there? Do I just wrap that around my existing code?

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry, submitted too early... please see my additions to the above comment.

Comment: `$.browser.device` returns boolean. So something like `if ($.browser.device == true) { // your jquery script here };`

Comment: @Blazemonger refer to support info link in answer.

Comment: Yes, so if someone's using 1.9 or later your code will throw an error, and your answer is incorrect. Please don't post answers that don't work.

Comment: So, it would be written out like this (apologies again; I'm really new to learning javascript/jquery):
`code`
if ($.browser.device != (/iPhone/iPad/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()) {



  <script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
   $.fancybox.open({
    padding: 0,
    content: elements,
    type: "html"
   });

   $("#myVideo").on("ended", function () {
    $.fancybox.close();
   });

  }); 
  };
`code`

Comment: Alright, so it seems that wouldn't work on more recent versions of jQuery then, huh?

Unfortunately, I'm trying to implement this into a friend's Squarespace site, so I think serverside solutions aren't going to work. 

Hmmmm, this is tougher than I thought it would be...

Comment: @DavidSchneider you don't need `<script>` tags in the code. Check my edits.

Comment: Thanks Xenyal, I will try that later when I can. In the meantime, I just made a duplicate version of the page without the jquery, and then used some simple javascript to redirect there if a ipad or iphone was detected. It's kludgy, but it works for the moment.